# How to show text from bottom when Hover

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am looking for some css trick to show an element (already hidden) from bottom to a it's normal position.

This is a screenshot how it should be:
[image: simple + hover]

i did this but it doesn't work as i expected and like what is on the screenshot, when you hover, the text should slide to the top. i made that, but with this method i did, the title is a little bit far from the text bellow ( screenshot )

Please can somebody help to find a lite solution

[image]

Please can somebody help me to find a lite solution

```css
.hebergements__container {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     margin: auto;
   width: 30rem;
}
 .hebergements__container::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #ccc;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     opacity: 1;
     height: auto;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
     transition-delay: 0.05s;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
     transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc, .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__title {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 .hebergements__container > img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .hebergements__content {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     min-height: 41.8rem;
     padding-left: 2.5rem;
     padding-bottom: 2.8rem;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title {
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     color: #fff;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc ul:first-child {
     margin-top: 0;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__startFrom {
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     color: #fff;
     margin-bottom: -0.8rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__price {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.4rem;
     font-weight: fontWeight(extra-bold);
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__price .price-unity {
     font-size: 1.6rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__pension {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 1rem;
     margin-top: 0.3rem;
}
 .hebergements__content {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 2em;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title, .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0);
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title {
     transition: transform 0.35s;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.35s;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__title, .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     transition-delay: 0.05s;
     transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container product-hebergements"> 
   <div class="hebergements__container">
                        <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/12.jpg" alt="img12"/>
      <div class="hebergements__content">
         <h2 class="hebergements__title">
            Votre séjour en Club
         </h2>

         <div class="hebergements__desc">
            <ul>
               <li>En chambre ou en appartement</li>
               <li>Capacité à partir de 2 personnes jusqu'à 10 personnes.</li>
               <li>Formule pension demi pension inclus</li>
               <li>Profitez des activités...Services</li>
            </ul>
         </div>

         <div class="hebergements__bottom">
            <div class="hebergements__pension">
               8 jours/7 nuits . Pension complète. Prix par pers.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First you need to explain how you 'expect it to work'. We can't guess.... Font size? Location? Colors?

Comment: @ Rene van der Lende, 
  just like the screenshot, when you hover, the text should slide to the top. i made that, but with this method the title is a little bit far from the text bellow

Comment: @Rene van der Lende, i updated the post

Comment: @Rene van der Lende, try to add some long text after `<ul>` to see how it looks like

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try

```css
.hebergements__container {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     margin: auto;
   width: 30rem;
}
 .hebergements__container::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #ccc;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     opacity: 1;
     height: auto;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
     transition-delay: 0.05s;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
     transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc, .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__title {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 .hebergements__container > img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .hebergements__content {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     min-height: 41.8rem;
     padding-left: 2.5rem;
     padding-bottom: 2.8rem;
     z-index: 1;
     overflow: hidden; /* added this line */
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title {
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     color: #fff;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc ul:first-child {
     margin-top: 0;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__startFrom {
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     color: #fff;
     margin-bottom: -0.8rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__price {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.4rem;
     font-weight: fontWeight(extra-bold);
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__price .price-unity {
     font-size: 1.6rem;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__pension {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 1rem;
     margin-top: 0.3rem;
}
 .hebergements__content {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 2em;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title, .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0);
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__title {
     transition: transform 0.35s;
}
 .hebergements__content .hebergements__desc {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.35s;
     height: 2rem; /* added this line */
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__title, .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 .hebergements__container:hover .hebergements__desc {
     transition-delay: 0.05s;
     transition-duration: 0.35s;
     height: auto;  /* added this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="container product-hebergements"> 
   <div class="hebergements__container">
                        <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/12.jpg" alt="img12"/>
      <div class="hebergements__content">
         <h2 class="hebergements__title">
            Votre séjour en Club
         </h2>

         <div class="hebergements__desc">
            <ul>
               <li>En chambre ou en appartement</li>
               <li>Capacité à partir de 2 personnes jusqu'à 10 personnes.</li>
               <li>Formule pension demi pension inclus</li>
               <li>Profitez des activités...Services</li>
            </ul>
         </div>

         <div class="hebergements__bottom">
            <div class="hebergements__pension">
               8 jours/7 nuits . Pension complète. Prix par pers.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what i tried before seeing your post, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using my computer right now but, I think, to create your animation, you have to create a @keyframe. Basically, your 3 lines are hidden, and, when you hover it, a new style must be added, with the keyframe (and the visibility visible).

Your keyframe must contain something like :
Transform: translateX (you have to make your div go to the top)
Animation fill mode forward

This is not complete, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of debugging your code trying to workaround/find your errors, I created a 'generic' animated card based on your code and requirement.

The entire mechanism hinges on flexbox behaviour:

- FBL column containers, for easy positioning
- FBL content moved to `flex-end`. This forces all elements to the bottom of the card.
- FBL 'flex-basis' animated `.header` from `0%` to `40%`. As the un-hovered value is `0%` all elements reside at the bottom of the card. When changed to a higher value (`< 40%`), the `.header` grows, pushing itself towards the top of the card. **This is the single main behaviour we need.**

Animating the properties of various elements from some initial value to a hover state value moves/shows/sizes the end result.

*BONUS* some card hover/click action I always use.

I have commented the code, which makes reading a bit easier...

The Snippet

```css
/* for debugging, remove/disable when done */
/* * { outline: 1px dashed }/**/

/***********************/
/* element definitions */
/***********************/
.card {
    position: relative;

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30rem; /* not responsive!! */
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
.card > * { /* picture and content */
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0; /* stretched to fill parent (T/R/B/L) */
}

/* background picture under all content, stretched to fit parent */
.card .bg-pic     { z-index: -1 }
.card .bg-pic img { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover }

/* Flexbox container over card background image */
.card .inner {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 1rem;

    justify-content: flex-end; /* move all elements to .inner bottom */
}

.card .inner > * {
    /* all card .inner elements are FBL column containers */
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;
 } 

/********************************/
/* All hover animation settings */
/********************************/
/*
    element defaults before animation with transitions set,
    followed by animation settings.
*/
.card {
    /* trasition properties, delay, behaviour */
    --tr-f: all 0.05s ease-in-out; /* fast transition */
    --tr-s: all 0.35s ease-in-out; /* slow */
}

.card .header { 
    flex-basis: 0%; /* makes it shrink to HTML default */
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: var(--tr-f);
}
.card:hover .header  {
    /* When content/footer tend to wrap, fiddle with below 'flex-basis' < 40% */
    flex-basis: 40%; /* makes it stretch to fill 40% */
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .bg-pic {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: var(--tr-s);
}
.card:hover .bg-pic  {
    opacity: 1;
}

.card .content {
    /* hides fading text under pricing */
    overflow: hidden; /* disable to test */

    height : 0px;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: var(--tr-s);
}
.card:hover .content {
    height : auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

/*************/
/* Eye-candy */
/*************/

body { font-size: 1rem }

ul, li { padding: 0; list-style-type: none }

.card > * {
     /* obfuscate picture for testing */
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%,.5);/* remove me */
    color:  hsl(0,0%,100%,1);

    cursor: pointer;
}

.title { font-size: 1.5rem }
.prix  { font-size: 2.4rem; font-weight: bold }
.unit  { font-size: 1.6rem }

/* BONUS: card hover/click animation */
.card {
    /* GMD elevation 1dp */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 1px 1px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 3px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    /* GMD elevation 3dp */
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 3px 4px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.card:active:not(:focus), .card:focus {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="bg-pic"><img src="https://picsum.photos/320" alt="" aria-hidden="true" /></div>

    <div class="inner">
        <div class="header">
            <div>Votre séjour en Club</div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li class="title">some alt title</li>
                <li>En chambre ou en appartement</li>
                <li>Capacité à partir de 2 personnes jusqu'à 10 personnes.</li>
                <li>Formule pension demi pension inclus</li>
                <li>Profitez des activités...Services</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <span>A partir de</span>
            <span class="prix">529<span class="unit">&euro;</span></span>
            <div>8 jours/7 nuits . Pension complète. Prix par pers.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```